# Cannot find a file named webdriver.json' or an embedded resource with the id 'WebDriver.FirefoxPreferences

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, selenium, asp.net-core

I am trying to do some selenium tests on my new unit test project:

My code is:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;
using System;

namespace HelloWorldDevOpsUnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ChucksClass1
    {
        private string baseURL = "http://localhost:5000/";
        private RemoteWebDriver driver;
        private string browser;
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("Selenium")]
        [Priority(1)]
        [Owner("FireFox")]

        public void TireSearch_Any()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(@"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe"), new FirefoxProfile(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this.baseURL);
            driver.FindElementById("search - box").Clear();
            driver.FindElementById("search - box").SendKeys("tire");
            //do other Selenium things here!
        }

        [TestCleanup()]
        public void MyTestCleanup()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }

        [TestInitialize()]
        public void MyTestInitialize()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I got these errors when running:

> Message: Test method
>   HelloWorldDevOpsUnitTests.ChucksClass1.TireSearch_Any threw exception:
>   OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find a file named
>   'C:\Users\valencil\DevOpsTest\HelloWorldDevOpsUnitTests\bin\Debug\webdriver.json'
>   or an embedded resource with the id 'WebDriver.FirefoxPreferences'.
>   TestCleanup method
>   HelloWorldDevOpsUnitTests.ChucksClass1.MyTestCleanup threw exception.
>   System.NullReferenceException: System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object..

Comment: I've encountered this before, and the issue is that the version of Selenium that supports .NET Standard either doesn't find the working directly correctly, so the files appear missing, or it doesn't compile the resources into the binary for them to be used automatically. I can't remember which of the two it is. I currently use a custom build of the Selenium assemblies to work around the problem.

The NullReferenceException is caused by driver being null and you calling Quit() on it.

Comment: what do you mean with a custom build? you download selenium source, build it and add as references?

Comment: More or less. I forked the repo, fixed the problem, and then published the fixed package to a private NuGet feed.

Comment: way too much trouble for me! should be easier

Comment: I am currently experiencing this same issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your project, the Selenium web driver binary should be copied to the output directory of your test project (e.g. /bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/). Try passing in the relative path to this binary to the XDriver constructor:

```
IWebDriver driver;
switch (browser.ToLower())
{
    case "firefox":
       driver = new FirefoxDriver("./");
    break;
    case "chrome":
       driver = new ChromeDriver("./");
    break;
    case "ie":
    case "internetexplorer":
       driver = new InternetExplorerDriver("./");
    break;
    case "phantomjs":
       driver = new PhantomJSDriver("./");
    break;
    default:
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver("./");
    break;   
}
```